# Add character after regex match if match is enclosed with space chars

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like the below

```
LP some company LLP address london LLP
LLP some other company LP address london LP
```

I need a regex that replaces the LP and LLP inside the sentence and ignores matches at the beginning or the end.

Result should be:

```
LP some company LLP, address london LLP
LLP some other company LP, address london LP
```

What I have so far is:

```
import re
text = "LP address, company LP bar foo LLP"
re.sub(r'(?<!^)LP', ' LP,', text)
```

Which outputs this:
 `'LP address, company  LP, bar foo L LP,'`

Which almost worked! If not that it split the LLP at the end and added a comma.

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong is highly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?!^)\s*\bL?LP\b(?!$)', ' LP,', text)`, see https://regex101.com/r/EZWRwO/1

Comment: Ok, is https://regex101.com/r/EZWRwO/1 what you need? Maybe, also exclude a position before comma, `(?!^)\s*\bL?LP\b(?!,|$)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could match:

`(LL?P)`

- - A single space.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group:

  - `LL?P` - Match an uppercase "L" once or twice followed by uppercase "P".
  - `)` - Close capture group.
- - A single space.

Replace with:  `\1,`

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/i5hZiG/1).

Comment: Ah!! Thank you! this is really lean - thank you again. I'll accept in 6 minutes .